# Exception: Too many read attempts detected in StreamIO /var/www/html/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php 252

Tags: php, push, php-amqplib

Exception: Too many read attempts detected in StreamIO 
/var/www/html/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php

Comment: A little more context may help people answer your question better. I assume this is from https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib If so I suggest submitting this error to their issues page.

Comment: I help maintain this library. Please don't just submit this error as an issue in php-amqplib on GitHub. You have to provide PHP version, library version, AMQP broker, and steps to reproduce. Without that information I can't help.